# POCO-Liberaries:: Poco Key expiry time not working in set method

Tags: poco-libraries

I am using Poco Redis Database that stores Key value pair using set command.
my requirement is to delete the entry after 7 days automatically.

i am using poco redis set command to achieve the functionality.

below is the signature for the set command :-

Command Command::set(const std::string& key, const std::string& value, bool overwrite, const Poco::Timespan& expireTime, bool create)

i am Following below procedure:-

1. first i am connecting to redis data base.
2. after successful connection, i am creating timespan object with 60 second value and passing key, value and timespan value to set method.

Timespan ts(60,0);

Command setCommand = Command::set(str_metadatakey, str_metadatavalue,true,ts,true);
std::string result = m_oRedisClient.execute(setCommand);

but when i am executing above code it is throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem.
Exception was "ERR Protocol error: expected '$', got ':'" - as redis expected "expire" to be string.

As a workaround you can explicitly specify expire as string:

```
Command setCommand = Command::set(key, value);
setCommand  << "EX" << "1500"
```